# Is there a way to prevent new line after 80 characters in output created by powershell script executed via ssh from linux?

Tags: java, powershell

I'm developing Linux expect script that:

1. makes ssh connection to Windows host command prompt.
2. Accesses powershell.
3. Navigates to existing folder on windows and invokes a powershell script.
4. Power shell script saves output to a text file.

When I run Linux script using Java, the powershell is executed successfully. However, output file created by powershell script is only 80 chars wide. 
When I run the script manually (via terminal and pass arguments manually), the output file is created without new lines after 80 chars.

I've tried to change encoding to utf8 and utf16 in powershell, but it doesn't resolve the issue

```
Get-MsolDomainFederationSettings -DomainName "example.com" | Out-File "C:\temp\fedSettings.txt"

Get-MsolDomainFederationSettings -DomainName "example.com" | Format-List * | Out-File "C:\temp\fedSettings.txt" -Encoding utf8

Get-MsolDomainFederationSettings -DomainName "example.com" | Format-List * | Out-File "C:\temp\fedSettings.txt" -Encoding utf16
```

I have also, ensured that the expect scripts do not have any Ctrl+M characters.

This is script that I execute via java ProcessBuilder

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20

#This expect script script invokes an existing script in Windows Powershell on a Windows Host via SSH from Linux.

set WINDOWS_HOST_NAME [lindex $argv 0]
set WINDOWS_USER [lindex $argv 1]
set WINDOWS_PASSWORD [lindex $argv 2]
set WINDOWS_FOLDER_PATH [lindex $argv 3]
set SCRIPT_FILE_NAME [lindex $argv 4]

spawn ssh $WINDOWS_USER@$WINDOWS_HOST_NAME

expect "yes/no" { 
    send "yes\r"
    expect "*?assword" { send "$WINDOWS_PASSWORD\r" }
    } "*?assword" { send "$WINDOWS_PASSWORD\r" }

expect "*$WINDOWS_USER*"
send "powershell\r";
send "cd $WINDOWS_FOLDER_PATH\r"

send "\.\\$SCRIPT_FILE_NAME\r"

send "exit\r"
send "exit\r"

interact
```

This is the powershell script that exists in windows and gets invoked by linux script.

```bsh
$AdminUser = "someone.com"
$Pswd = Get-Content "C:/creds/cred1" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminUser, $Pswd
$dom = "example.com"
$dateTime = Get-Date -f "MMddyyyy_HHmm"

Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred

Get-MsolDomainFederationSettings -DomainName $dom | Format-List * | Out-File "C:\temp\fedSettings.txt"
$filenameFormat = "fedSettings_$(Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy_HHmm").txt"
Rename-Item -Path "C:\temp\fedSettings" -NewName $filenameFormat
```

I'm expecting that when PowerShell creates an output file, the new line is introduced only if content/data of the line is complete.
However, the output file created is limited to only `80 chars` when executed via java/automated. 
But, when I execute the expect script manually, then, the file is fine.

Comment: Have a look at [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6#parameters). It has a `-Width` parameter you can set to a larger number (largest is  `[int]::MaxValue`). If you don't, you will hit the 80 characters default value.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me.I also found another post with similar topic https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Server-Automation-User/Line-wrap-on-output-of-Powershell-Scripts-in-SA/m-p/1658428#M4713